# How to export data to an excel file w/chart on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, excel, export, export-to-excel, xls

I have some data in a sqlite database in my app, and my client wants an option that allows you to email it as an excel file which includes a chart of the data.  Is this possible on an iPhone?

Have a good one,

Toby

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just take the data from your database and generate and excel file with it, formatted as your requirements. Then simply send the file you created using [MFMailComposeViewController](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html).

The specification for an XLS file can be found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/interop/docs/officebinaryformats.mspx#EXB).